# Creation of an instance with `with` block causes a type issue

Tags: groovy, casting, closures, with-statement, object-initializers

I am using Groovy to create a package that I use in ReadyApi.

In a Groovy script test step, I do the following:

```
class B  {
    String value
    boolean isSomething
}

class A {
    String name
    B propB

    public A() {
        this.name = "Maydan"
    }
}

def x = (A) new A().with  { propB = new B(value: "Abc", isSomething: true) }
```

And I get the following error:

> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'B@6c218cea' with class 'B' to class 'A'
> error at line: 15

Does someone know why? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Kind regards.

PS: I would like to create an instance of class A (by using its parameterless constructor) and setting its field propB in a single statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return your `A` object from the `.with` closure. You may do it like that:

```
def x = (A) new A().with  { propB = new B(value: "Abc", isSomething: true); return it}
```

but to me personally it looks a little bit odd. I would do it like that:

```
def x = new A(propB: new B(value: "Abc", isSomething: true))
```

The same effect, but more compact and readable. It doesn't require to change your `A` and `B` definitions, this "map constructor" works out of the box in Groovy, it will call your parameterless constructor and then assigns the necessary fields (`propB` in your case).

Comment: Thank you very much! My understanding was biased by my knowledge of C# object-initializers (since I am normally a C# dev). (By the way, the second solution doesn't fit my needs since I want to call the parameterless constructor defined in A)

Comment: @AymenTurki I've updated my answers, you do not need to re-define A or B, it will work for you without any changes as you want it. It's Groovy syntax sugar.